# The ConnectionString option in appsettings.json file giving parse error after deployed under IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project. In `appsettings.json` file, I have the following connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LabConnectionString": "Server=1234-98761\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
  }
}
```

It is working fine when the project is executed from Visual Studio. But when it is deployed in the IIS server after compiling, I am getting the following error found in a log file:

> Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '9': '"ConnectionStrings": {
> "LabConnectionString": "data source=1234-98761;initial catalog=db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",'.
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Bad JSON escape sequence: \S. Path 'ConnectionStrings.LabConnectionString', line 9, position 52.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add double back slashes`\\` before SQLEXPRESS. Update your code like below:-

```
"LabConnectionString": "Server=1234-98761\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
```

and your `startup.cs` file:-

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

Hope It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON format, inside a string the backslash character is used as escape for other special character, and for itself too.

Here is a self explanatory image from [Douglas Crockford](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)'s and [ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/)'s JSON specs

[image]

So, you have to escape the backslash:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LabConnectionString": "Server=1234-98761\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "providerName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
  }
}
```